# How to sum up conditionally columns pairwise on an asymmetric dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, pairwise

Here is a simplified version of my problem:

```
import pandas as pd

v1 = [1, 5, 0]
v2, v2_tocomb = [2, 4, 9], [0, 1, 0]
v3, v3_tocomb = [3, 3, 8], [2, 0, 1]
v4, v4_tocomb = [0, 7, 6], [1, 1, 1]
v5 = [2, 2, 6]
v1_1 = [3, 4, 1]
v2_1, v2_tocomb_1 = [4, 2, 8], [2, 1, 0]
v3_1, v3_tocomb_1 = [1, 1, 7], [1, 1, 0]
v4_1 = [0, 0, 5]
v5_1 = [9, 5, 5]

data = pd.DataFrame({'v1': v1, 'v2': v2, 'v2_tocomb': v2_tocomb, 'v3': v3, 'v3_tocomb': v3_tocomb, 'v4': v4, 'v4_tocomb': v4_tocomb, 'v5': v5,
                    'v1_1': v1_1, 'v2_1': v2_1, 'v2_tocomb_1': v2_tocomb_1, 'v3_1': v3_1, 'v3_tocomb_1': v3_tocomb_1, 'v4_1': v4_1, 'v5_1': v5_1})

# what to do? #

data_final = pd.DataFrame({'v1': v1, 'v2_comb': [sum(x) for x in zip(v2, v2_tocomb)], 'v3_comb': [sum(x) for x in zip(v3, v3_tocomb)], 'v4_comb': [sum(x) for x in zip(v4, v4_tocomb)], 'v5': v5,
                           'v1_1': v1_1, 'v2_comb_1': [sum(x) for x in zip(v2_1, v2_tocomb_1)], 'v3_comb_1': [sum(x) for x in zip(v3_1, v3_tocomb_1)], 'v4_1': v4_1, 'v5_1': v5_1})
```

This is the starting dataset (*data*):

| v1 | v2 | v2_tocomb | v3 | v3_tocomb | v4 | v4_tocomb | v5 | v1_1 | v2_1 | v2_tocomb_1 | v3_1 | v3_tocomb_1 | v4_1 | v5_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 9 |
| 5 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 7 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 9 | 0 | 8 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 5 | 5 |

And this is the desired output (*data_final*):

| v1 | v2_comb | v3_comb | v4_comb | v5 | v1_1 | v2_comb_1 | v3_comb_1 | v4_1 | v5_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 9 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 | 8 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 9 | 9 | 7 | 6 | 1 | 8 | 7 | 5 | 5 |

The main task is to sum values pairwise for columns that have `_comb` in their name and the corresponding variable. For example columns `v2` and `v2_tocomb` need to be summed up together in the new column `v2_comb` (then `v2` and `v2_tocomb` are dropped). The same happens for columns ending with `_1`, for example, `v3_1` and `v3_tocomb_1` are combined in the new column `v3_comb_1`.

I can get *data_final* for this simplified version of the dataset by doing the described process "by hand", but the original problem refers to 200+ columns, so I need to find a way to automate the process. Furthermore, the original features' names aren't that simple (`v1`, `v2`, and so on), but it shouldn't be a problem.

In my opinion, what makes this problem tricky is that the columns to combine can both end with `_tocomb` or `_tocomb_1` and that there is no symmetry, hence a column doesn't necessarily have another one to be summed up with and columns ending with `_1` don't follow the same path of the "original" ones.

Actually, I am using only *pandas* library but I could use any other Python library to achieve the desired output. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `_comb` and [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
grp = data.columns.str.replace('_tocomb', '', regex=True)

data_final = data.groupby(grp, axis=1, sort=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
   v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v1_1  v2_1  v3_1  v4_1  v5_1
0   1   2   5   1   2     3     6     2     0     9
1   5   5   3   8   2     4     3     2     0     5
2   0   9   9   7   6     1     8     7     5     5
```

Then modify the columns names if needed with [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
cols = {c.replace('_tocomb', ''): c.replace('_tocomb', '_comb')
        for c in data.columns.difference(data_final.columns)}
data_final = data_final.rename(columns=cols)
```

Output:

```
   v1  v2_comb  v3_comb  v4_comb  v5  v1_1  v2_comb_1  v3_comb_1  v4_1  v5_1
0   1        2        5        1   2     3          6          2     0     9
1   5        5        3        8   2     4          3          2     0     5
2   0        9        9        7   6     1          8          7     5     5
```

Comment: thank you so much both for editing my question and for your clear answer, it was really helpful! I just added these lines at the end to drop duplicated columns and get back to the original order (columns ending with `_1` to the right): `data_final = data_final.iloc[:,~data_final.columns.duplicated()]
cols_to_move = data_final.filter(regex='_1$').columns
data_final = data_final.drop(columns=cols_to_move).join(data_final[cols_to_move])`

Comment: @Angel, I forgot to add `sort=False` see update

Comment: you're right, I added it and I was able to get rid of the last two lines of code. Thank you!